# Ggplot geom_point error in shinyapps.io but not in local machine: Found object is not a stat

Tags: r, windows, ggplot2, shiny

I am trying to build a reactive plotting application in shiny using ggplot2 and geom_point. I am using a local dataset, loading it from the './myApp/data' location, applying some clustering and filtering within the reactive function using helper functions I wrote before-hand and returning the final data.

When I plot this data in the local machine, the plot shows up exactly as I want it. The app works in shinyapps when I use base plotting system or plotly as well. But when I deploy the app to the shinyapps.io with ggplot code, I get the error saying

> Error: 'Found object is not a stat'.

I added code below. I would appreciate all help.

```
cluster_fun <- function(data){
cluster <- Mclust(data)
//Somehow merge cluster and data to get centers, memberships etc. Nothing fancy here
return(list(data,cluster))
}

filter_cluster_data <- function(data, , min_time, max_time, sd, dbs){
//Filter data based on inputs min_time, max_time, sd, dbs. These are taken from the user in the shinyapp
temp_list <- cluster_fun(filtered_data)
return(temp_list)
}

server <- function(input, output) {
plot_data <- reactive({
dat <- obs_data[[input$tn]]
min_time <- input$time[1]*60
max_time <- input$time[2]*60
sd <- input$ts

divideByS <- input$divideByS
colorByNW <- input$colorByNW
grouped <- input$gw

cw <- filter_cluster_data(dat, input$time[1]*60, input$time[2]*60, input$ts, input$divideByS)
pre_h_rad <- cw[[1]]
cluster_members <- cw[[2]]
if(grouped){
  dat <- cluster_members
}else{
  dat <- pre_h_rad
}
return(dat)})
```

The following is the part where I keep getting the error. The app works fine in local machine. I also load the img variable to the shinyapps so that's not the problem either. I also removed those lines and I still get the same error with an empty geom_point() call.

```
output$distPlot <- renderPlot({

# Grouped
if(input$gw){
  p <- ggplot(plot_data(), aes(x=center_x, y=center_y)) +
    geom_point(shape=19,      # Use solid circles
               alpha=input$alpha,
               aes(color=tgd, size=sz
               )) +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = round(seq(0, 128, by = 10),1), limits=c(0,128)) +
    scale_y_continuous(breaks = round(seq(0, 128, by = 10),1), limits=c(0,128)) +
    scale_size_continuous(name="Number of data points in cluster", range = c(4,8))  +
    annotation_custom(rasterGrob(img, width=unit(1,"npc"), height=unit(1,"npc")), 0, 128, 0, 128)


}else{
  p <- # Single
    ggplot(plot_data(), aes_string(x="x_true", y="y_true")) +
    geom_point(shape=19,      # Use solid circles
               alpha=input$alpha, size=6,
               aes(color=tgd
               )) + geom_jitter(height = 0.01, width = 0.01) +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = round(seq(0, 128, by = 10),1), limits=c(0,128)) +
    scale_y_continuous(breaks = round(seq(0, 128, by = 10),1), limits=c(0,128)) +
    annotation_custom(rasterGrob(img, width=unit(1,"npc"), height=unit(1,"npc")), 0, 128, 0, 128)

}
if(input$colorByNW){
  p<-p + scale_color_gradient2(name="NW",low = "red", mid = "black",high = "green",
                               midpoint = 0)
}

if(input$divideByS){
  p<-p + facet_wrap(~sw)
}
p
```

})

EDIT: I ended up using base-R plot dur to this issue, and got the app working. 
I would still appreciate it if anyone can answer this though.

Comment: This may not be directly pertinent to your problem, but in definition of `filter_cluster_data `, you define many arguments, but use none of them. Have you tried, locally, restarting your R environment? Perhaps there's some "leaking" of data which makes things work locally but not in a new (remote) session?

Comment: I am using all of them, I just didn't put any of it here so I wouldn't clutter the page. I have restarted the environment, the computer, the session. The behavior remains the same.

Comment: It's hard to work without a reproducible example. Consider commenting out to see which line is offending and work from there.

Comment: I tried that too. Nothing changes. Also the plot shows in shinyapps when I use base plotting system, plotly or basically anything else. Just not with ggplot.

Comment: Then you have not commented out enough. :)